# COM exception - this document is locked for editing - but it isn't

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I'm encountering a COM Exception that the document is locked for editing when I try to insert a comment with the following code - sometimes. The document's protection mode is set to  `WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyComments`, and it is never changed from that. There are no protected regions in the document or locked content controls.

I have a set of inputs that reproduces the issue. It invokes the method five times with five sets of inputs. Two of them give the error. There is nothing to distinguish the two from the others, and nothing particular that they have in common.

If I immediately retry the operation with the same inputs, it succeeds. However, it leaves an empty comment in the same position afterwards, which seems undetectable in the catch clause (I will look at that further to see if it is in fact not in the Comments collection in the active document).

```
    public IWordComment AddComment(int scopeStart, int scopeEnd, string text)
    {
        var scopeRange = _document.Range(scopeStart, scopeEnd);
        object cText = text;
        Comment newComment = null;
        try
        {
            newComment = _document.Comments.Add(scopeRange, cText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var itisntlockedthough = _document.ProtectionType;
            ...
```

I've determined that having an event handler on entering a content control code causes the error to occur. I'm guessing that it is occurring when the comment being added is in a different content control than the cursor is currently in, and the code is triggered. I still don't know why this code causes it. Nothing is locked in it. I suspect any event handler would have the same effect.

```
private void Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ContentControl cc)
{
    // Select the corresponding item in the review view model.

    if (cc.ParentContentControl == null )
    {
        var tag = cc.Tag;
        if (tag == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (tag.StartsWith("tbl:"))
        {
            var id = int.Parse(cc.Tag.Substring(4));
            _reviewViewModel.SelectTable(id);
        }
        else if (!tag.StartsWith("var:"))
        {
            Guid id;
            if (Guid.TryParse(cc.Tag, out id))
            {
                _reviewViewModel.SelectItem(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can just turn off the event handler when I am making the inserts. So I've fixed the problem - but I still don't actually know why it happens, so I'll leave this question open for a while in case anyone can tell me.

Comment: Is it in reading layout mode? <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.view.readinglayout> Editing documents is not allowed in this mode. <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.view.readinglayout?view=word-pia>

Comment: [Read documents in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/read-documents-in-word-5ea57c11-94f1-4fa2-895a-bc5e6d204a81).

Comment: No it's not. The same edit succeeds if tried immediately after the failure. The failed insert does in fact result in an empty comment being inserted.

Comment: *IWordComment*, *WdCommentsOnly* These are your own definitions, right? You only general description of the situation, and no more complete code and test data, no wonder not many people can answer

Comment: I meant WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyComments. IWordComment is just an abstraction of the interop Comment object so I can use DI and unit tests.  It's not obvious what other code is relevant. There's >6k lines of code in it so pasting arbitrary portions isn't useful.

Answer (score -1):

Your description is too general, and I do not know where the problem lies. After trying to reproduce the scenario in your code as follows, I did not encounter any errors:

```cs
    public partial class ThisDocument
    {
        private void ThisDocument_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.ActiveDocument.Range().InsertAfter("...");
            AddComment(10, 20, "南無阿彌陀佛");
            AddComment(10, 20, "阿彌陀佛");
            AddComment(10, 20, "海賢老和尚");
            AddComment(30, 31, "大藏經");
            AddComment(40, 51, "恩師上淨下空老和尚");
        }

        private void ThisDocument_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        
        public Word.Comment AddComment(int scopeStart, int scopeEnd, string text)
        //public IWordComment AddComment(int scopeStart, int scopeEnd, string text)
        {
            Word.Document _document = this.Application.ActiveDocument;
            var scopeRange = _document.Range(scopeStart, scopeEnd);
            object cText = text;
            Comment newComment = null;
            try
            {
                newComment = _document.Comments.Add(scopeRange, cText);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var itisntlockedthough = _document.ProtectionType;
                //...
            }
            return newComment;
        }

}
```

> I have a set of inputs that reproduces the issue. It invokes the method five times with five sets of inputs. Two of them give the error.

Maybe you should give me the text that will cause the code error and these 5 sets of test data for me to try.

**content control**? Your previous question did not mention this at all. I'm sorry. I'm afraid you have to be more diligent in describing the context in which your problem occurs. I'll check it out again sometime. If no one answers.

> I can just turn off the event handler when I am making the inserts. So I've fixed the problem

**event handler** ? Your original problem scenario did not mention this at all, who knows? So I'm not wrong to say that there is nothing wrong with testing. When you ask someone a question, you should also express your operating environment and the code blocks you touched in full. Try to recreate as much as possible the situation when your question occurred, for the convenience of those who want to answer your question. Otherwise, how it be considered a good question?